# How to avoid gratuitous copy/paste in Puppet manifests?

Tags: puppet

```
`package {
"apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4_amd64(1)":
ensure => present,
provider => 'dpkg',
source => "/home/apache/apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4_amd64(1).deb",
require => File["/home/apache/apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4_amd64(1).deb"],
subscribe => Exec["dpkg --install"],
install_options => ["INSTLLDIR=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"],   
}
package {
"apache2-bin_2.4.7-1ubuntu4_amd64":
ensure => present,
provider => 'dpkg',
source => "/home/apache/apache2-bin_2.4.7-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb",
require => File["/home/apache/apache2-bin_2.4.7-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb"],
subscribe => Exec["dpkg --install"],
install_options => ["INSTLLDIR=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"],
}
package {
"libapr1_1.5.0-1_amd64":
ensure => present,
provider => 'dpkg',
source => "/home/apache/libapr1_1.5.0-1_amd64.deb",
require => File["/home/apache/libapr1_1.5.0-1_amd64.deb"],
subscribe => Exec["dpkg --install"],
install_options => ["INSTLLDIR=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"],
}`
```

I have to write this code in package section not in multiple section of packages when I am installing the package with lots of dependency.
because the code was very lengthy.
So how to write the code when the package have more dependency and in one package section?
e.g.
I have to write the whole package dependency code in one package section like

```
package {

}
```

How to reduce this code in small no.of lines?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case - just don't. Set up a local `apt` repository and stop copying `.deb` files around.

Generally, to avoid copy/pasting:

Create a defined type to wrap the resources.

```
define common_package($ensure=present, $source, $provider='dpkg') {
    package {
       $title:
           ensure => $ensure,
           provider => $provider,
           source => $source,
           require => File[$source],
           subscribe => Exec["dpkg --install"],
           install_options => ["INSTLLDIR=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"],
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
common_package { 
    'apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4_amd64(1)':
        source => '/home/apache/apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4_amd64(1).deb';
    'apache2-bin_2.4.7-1ubuntu4_amd64':
        source => '/home/apache/apache2-bin_2.4.7-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb';
    'libapr1_1.5.0-1_amd64':
        source => '/home/apache/libapr1_1.5.0-1_amd64.deb';
}
```